# r append/rbind identical tables contained in different list in a loop

Tags: r, list, merge, append

Given C1 and C2 below (it is a simplicfication):

```
a2 <- c("a","b","c")
A <- cbind(a1, a2)

b1 <- c("bergkamp","Van Basten")
b2 <- c("pires","wiltord")
B <- cbind(a1, a2)

C1 = list("A" =A, "B" = B)

a1 <- c(4,5,6)
a2 <- c("d","e","f")
A <- cbind(a1, a2)

b1 <- c("Overmars","Blind")
b2 <- c("Anelka","Zidane")
B <- cbind(a1, a2)

C2 = list("A" =A, "B" = B)
```

how can I have a list where A in C1 is appended to A in C2 the same for all the tabs with the same name in the list? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another base R option with `Map` + `rbind`

```
Map(rbind,C1,C2)
```

Comment: if C1 and C2 are the output of a loop. i.e. C for i =1 and C for i = 2. I tried: Final <- list(), Final <- Map(rbind(Final,C) in the loop but it does not work. Any suggestion?

Comment: @highbury_85 Could you post your question with more details?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rbind` with `do.call`

```
do.call(rbind, c(C1, C2))
```